# notification for a user chosen time for different users on the same device

Tags: android, notifications, push-notification

I have read this tutorial about creating notification for a user chosen time using class Service and Binder.

```
http://blog.blundell-apps.com/notification-for-a-user-chosen-time/
```

My question is what if different users log in from the same device.. how can the system recognize which nitifications belong to each user?

what other ways can I create notifications system where the system pop up a notification when the selected date comes around, taking into considaration that from the same device differen users can log in.